# Git - Show when the last modification was to a folder

Tags: git

Is there a way to determine or to get a summary of modification dates made to a specific folder ?

Comment: Have you checked out `man git-log`?

Comment: Can you read [ask] and show what you have tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The following command](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-log) shows the history of all commits affecting the sub directory:

```sh
$ git log -- <path>
```

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR** The command you need is

```
git log --pretty='format:%h %aI' -- <path>
```

I recommend checking [the man page](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log) of `git-log`.

The synopsis says:

```
git log [<options>] [<revision range>] [[--] <path>…​]
```

(Notice how there's a `<path>` argument?)

[The description](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---ltpathgt82308203) for `[--] <path>` reads:

> Show only commits that are enough to explain how the files that match the specified paths came to be.

So the command you're looking for is right `git log`, with path appended.

Since you're looking for modification times, using a custom [pretty format](https://git-scm.com/docs/pretty-formats) is better:

```
git log --pretty='format:%h %aI'
```

This will produce output like:

```
1234abc 2021-02-31T12:34:56+00:00
```

Combined with path arguments, the full command is as given at the top of this answer.

Comment: fatal: ambiguous argument '%aI'': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.